# iPad menu bar, collapse completely or move to right side?

Tags: feature-request, ios-app, ipad

Is there anyway to collapse the menu bar completely closed? Or relocate it to the right side?

I haven't found a way to collapse it completely or change its behavior in any way.  My issue is that I use my left thumb to scroll, and I'm constantly jumping to some other selection in the mini menu, if I'm not very careful to avoid it, and when I do jump somewhere there is no easy way back to the same spot.

So this is either a request for help using an existing feature or a feature request :]